# Enable connection from Hyper-V guest to Windows Server 2022 host

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, hyper-v, windows-server-2022

I have a Windows Server 2022 that has a VM running on Hyper-V. the VM is an Ubuntu Linux machine. I can ping all computers on the local network. as well as access Internet. But I cant seem to be able to access the host using ping or http. I am sure it is not a firewall issue since even after turning the firewall off completely it doesn't work. Tried everything I saw online but can't seem to figure this one out.

Also to Add. I can already access the VM from the host and other machines on the network. Ping or HTTP alike

Comment: Would the fact that there is only one physical NIC be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you setup your Virtual Switch, did you Select the "**Private**" Option? This may potentially explain why you cannot communicate with the VM from the Host Machine.

If this is the case, you'll want to Select the "**Internal**" Option.

You can find additional information here, if needed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/plan/plan-hyper-v-networking-in-windows-server#hyper-v-networking-basics

If this is not the issue, I would confirm that "Integrated Services" is Enabled, before reviewing your NAT Configuration, etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/470494/hyper-v-server-is-not-pinging

Comment: I can already access the VM from the host and other machines on the network. I should have mentioned this earlier. Updated the post

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I would check the Firewall, to ensure that ICMP is Allowed, on both ends.

**Allow ICMP/PING via Ubuntu Firewall (UFW):**
https://www.kelvinism.com/2010/09/enable-icmp-through-ufw_461.html?m=1

**Allow ICMP/PING via Windows Firewall:**
https://www.wintips.org/how-to-allow-ping-in-windows-firewall/

Comment: But isn't the same reason denying this solution as well? 
this one : I can already access the VM from the host and other machines on the network. Ping or HTTP alike

Comment: From what I understand, ICMP/PING is Disabled, by default. You may want to Run "SCONFIG". From there, you can Select "Configure Remote Management". Then Select "Configure Server Response to Ping". A Confirmation Message should be displayed. Simply Select "Yes", to Enable Ping Responses from the Server. https://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/windows/hyper-v-server/how_to_enable_ping.htm

Comment: The server is already pingable from other machines. Anyway I tried it and it didnt work. My question is that does this issue usually happen?

Comment: Okay. I was basing my suggestions on the "I cant seem to be able to access the host using ping or http" comment, in your OP. From what I understand, this is Default behavior, in regard to Hyper-V Core as well as Windows Server (2016, 2019 & 2022), via Windows Firewall. https://superuser.com/questions/1711743/why-one-server-is-able-to-ping-the-other-but-not-vice-versa

Comment: but if you see, I mentioned in the OP that I tried disabling the firewall and still didn't work. would the above comment still be valid?

Comment: I understand. I was just referencing the Firewall Rules as one example. You may also want to confirm that your Host and Guest are on the same Subnet. https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/184201-hyper-v-guest-cant-ping-host.html

Comment: One more, for now. i would also review the following Article, regarding Virtual Switch Security Policies, via Port ACLs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v-virtual-switch/create-security-policies-with-extended-port-access-control-lists

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, your situation of being able to ping and access resources on the local network and the internet from your Ubuntu Linux VM running on a Windows Server 2022 Hyper-V host is promising. However, encountering issues when attempting to access the host using both ping and HTTP requires some investigation. Several factors can contribute to this scenario, and here's a code snippet to help you troubleshoot and pinpoint the problem:

```
import subprocess

def ping_host(host):
  """Pings the host and returns True if the host is reachable, False otherwise."""

  ping_command = ["ping", "-c", "1", host]
  ping_process = subprocess.Popen(ping_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  ping_output, ping_error = ping_process.communicate()
  ping_process wait()

  if ping_process.returncode == 0:
    return True
  else:
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
  host = "192.168.1.100"  # Replace this with the IP address of your host

  if ping_host(host):
    print("The host is reachable.")
  else:
    print("The host is not reachable.")
```

This Python script allows you to check the reachability of your host by pinging its IP address. By saving this script as, say, "ping_host.py," and executing it on your Ubuntu Linux VM using the command python ping_host.py, you can determine if the host is reachable. If successful, it will display the message "The host is reachable." If not, it will show "The host is not reachable."

While the code helps assess the host's accessibility, several potential reasons might explain the issue. These include network adapter misconfigurations, incorrect IP settings, firewall rules, or even Hyper-V networking anomalies. To address these, make sure the VM's network adapter settings allow sharing with the management operating system. Verify that the VM's IP configuration matches the host's subnet. Check the host's firewall rules to ensure it allows ICMP (ping) and HTTP traffic from the VM.

If you've covered all these aspects and the issue persists, consider restarting both the Hyper-V service and the VM. Additionally, it's advisable to keep Hyper-V integration services updated on the VM and disable IPv6 as an extra measure.